# Separate users in two groups (staff and guests) in FreeRADIUS 3

Tags: groups, freeradius, wpa

I have a FreeRADIUS (3.0.15) server for WPA authentication (PEAP + MSCHAPv2) and everything works out of the box even though it feels like it would take a lifetime of study in an enclosed monastery to master every bit of the configuration.

I have my users in the `users` file and I would like to keep it that way (versus sql or ldap) because I like the convenience of editing users with a simple text editor.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I have two SSIDs (`staff` and `guests`) and I would like to separate my users in two groups such that a guest user is rejected if they try to authenticate on the `staff` SSID.

**What I have so far:**

In my `users` file:

```
DEFAULT
    MyGroup := 'guests',
    Fall-Through := Yes

# Guest users
guest1 Cleartext-Password := 'password1'
# End of guest users

DEFAULT
    MyGroup := 'staff',
    Fall-Through := Yes

# Staff users
staff1 Cleartext-Password := 'kdjsfhksf'
# End of staff users
```

My hope is that, after parsing the file, the `reply:MyGroup` attribute has `staff` or `guest` depending on what user matched the request.

My `dictionary` file has this:

```
ATTRIBUTE MyGroup 3000 string
```

And my `default` site has this in the `authorize` group, right after the `files` module. The `rewrite_called_station_id` creates a new attribute `Called-Station-SSID`, which I use along the `MyGroup` attr created by the `files` mod to try and filter the users:

```
# get SSID from Called-Station-Id
rewrite_called_station_id

# check guest connecting to staff SSID and reject if so
if (&MyGroup == 'guests' && &Called-Station-SSID == 'STAFF') {
        reject
}
```

I also tried this:

```
if (&reply:MyGroup == 'guests' && &Called-Station-SSID == 'STAFF') {
```

But in any case I get the following error:

```
if (&reply:MyGroup == 'guests' && &Called-Station-SSID == 'STAFF') {
ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
```

At this point I have no clue what's going on and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign groups to users do it with check items which insert items into the `&control` list, i.e.

```
guest1  Mygroup := 'guests', Cleartext-Password := 'password1'

staff1  Mygroup := 'staff', Cleartext-Password := 'kdjsfhksf'
```

and then

```
if ((&control:MyGroup == 'guests') && (&Called-Station-SSID == 'STAFF')) {
```

Comment: Aha! That's the missing piece I was looking for! You are my hero, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me where you coded that "if ((&control:MyGroup etc."

Asking because I've added a MyGroup variable as type string in my dictionary file, and changed the users file by adding a MyGroup item to a test user, and then done this in policy.d/filter:

if (&control:MyGroup == "TEST") && (&outer.request:Called-Station-Id !~ /.*:FORBIDDEN-SSID$/) {
update request {
&Module-Failure-Message += 'You may not connect to this network'
}
reject
}

However Freeadius is telling me "ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition"

Thanks!